# How to restrict user from editing the URL data in a java application and access the URL

Tags: java, security

I am developing a java application having front end in html5 and dojo. I am using SOAP as well as REST services tomake service calls to get data from downstream system. What I found is a potential threat in the application. Users are able to access the URL of the application and they are able to edit the URL.e.g. IF the user is viewing his profile and if he knews name of some other user then he can edit the URL to change the user name from his name to someother name and can change some other fields and hit the url. Likewise user can edit some sensitive data and get access to confidential information.

My question is  How can i prevent the user from editing the parameters in the application url?

Comment: Never trust user supplied values, and is this a `Java` or `JavaScript` question?

Comment: use `POST` instead of `GET`

Comment: This is java question. I am trying to prevent user from editing the url data

Comment: @TKS I don't believe you can, but even if you did - I can edit the values my browser sends. Now, on the server, you can use the `session` to store whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

What URL a user chooses to access is client side and can't necessarily be controlled. Anybody can easily open a new tab and type in whatever URL they want to.

I would instead suggest protecting your REST endpoints with some sort of server side security framework instead. If you're using Java on your server side, you could look into something like http://shiro.apache.org/ for security which would not allow any user to access data that they shouldn't have access to.

Another solution would be to just have a single REST endpoint that can access whatever profile the user's session currently refers to.